# R using ifelse to replace is.na with conditional average / median / mode

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have two columns "Sex" and "Age", where "Sex" is 1 for male and 2 for females. Age is a number presumably between 0.5 and 90 with `NA`s scattered around.

How do run an `ifelse` formula so I can fill the average age of Males and similarly Females when the age is `NA` for that corresponding cell?

[image]

How do I amend my code to help with this? Current code:

```
dataset$Age = ifelse(is.na(dataset$Age),
                 ave(dataset$Age, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)),
                 dataset$Age)
```

I would like have a separate average for Males and Females input in the `NA` spaces.

Thank you for your kind help in advance.

Comment: You should edit your question with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Edited as per the comments:

I can see this being solved in 2 steps:
 - First use aggregation to find the average ages by gender
 - Then use the ifelse

```
library(dplyr)
df_agg <- df %>% group_by(gender) %>% summarise(Age = mean(age, na.rm = TRUE))
male_avg <- df_agg$Age[df_agg$gender == 1]
female_avg <- df_agg$Age[df_agg$gender == 2]

df$age <- ifelse(is.na(df$age), ifelse(df$gender == 1, male_avg, female_avg), df$age)
```

Comment: Thank you. 

For others, the code works perfectly with a few small tweaks. 
Note: 
Add parenthesis at end of first line (   ex. ... na.rm = TRUE))  )
Also received Error for incorrect number of dimensions on male_avg and female_avg lines. Solution: delete ', 2' from both lines.

Otherwise great suggestions. Perfect.